# Is it possible to add a cookie in the ios/andriod simulator with detox?

Tags: automated-tests, detox

I use detox for app testing and for testing purposes I want to add extra cookies to the andriod/ios simulator so that I can use my stubs. Note that this cookie is not for each test the same so it can't be hardcoded in the code, but should be a variable in the test. However I don't know how to this, or if it is even possible. Does anyone know if this is possible and how I can do this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can pass launch arguments using Detox API, and you can add mocked entry point for your app to read the launch argument and set the cookie accordingly. So, for each test, pass a launch argument with the correct cookie for that test.

If you do not wish to launch for each test, you can set up a much more elaborate solution, where you can have a server which you can connect to from both the Detox test runner and app, but that sounds like an overkill here.